# Unable to decode email address with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm sending an email via jquery to a PHP page so when the address arrives on the server it looks like this:

```
emailaddress%40gmail.com
```

I'm trying to convert it with html_entiity_decode like so:

```
$values['emailaddress'] = 'emailaddress%40gmail.com';
$email_address = html_entity_decode($values['emailaddress']);
```

html_entity_decode doesn't seem to be working

Do I need to do something on the client side before handing it off to the server?

Comment: You are double-encoding stuff client-side?  It should be decoded for you automatically, if you are using `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email is url-encoded, not html-encoded.

```
$email_address = urldecode($values['emailaddress']);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an htmlentity, it's url encoding. Use [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).